# Asymptotics and bounds of $k$-divisor function $d_k(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, divisor-counting-function

Let $d_k(n)$ be the $k$-divisor function, i.e., it is a number of ways to represent $n$ as a product of $k$ natural numbers.

I'm interested in the asymptotic behavior (or, at least, in upper bounds) of $d_k(n)$ as $n \to \infty$ in the following two cases:

1) $k$ is fixed;

2) $k \to \infty$ in some monotone way, e.g., as $k = C \log(n)$ for some constant $C \in \left(0, \frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}\right)$.

---

I saw quite a lot of works about the behavior and bounds for the sum $\sum_{n \leq x} d_k(n)$. However, I was not able to find results concerning the behavior of $d_k(n)$ by itself. Thus, I'll appreciate even references to the proper literature.

Comment: $d_3$ is tabulated at http://oeis.org/A007425 and while no bounds are given there, there are several references there to the literature where you may find something (and I suspect if you find something about $d_3$, then $d_k$ won't be far behind).